# Replace 'NA' values in a column in a dataframe in R with values from another column in same dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, na

I'm new to R programming. I read a csv file. I want to replace certain 'NA' values in a column with values present in the same row from some other column. So I have written a 'if statement' shown below, but instead of replacing only the 'NA' values, all the values in that column are getting replaced by the values present in another column. What possibly is going wrong here? Any help is welcomed.
The data looks like

```
Group   Skill
 A1      ABC
 A1      ABC
 A1      ABC
 A1      ABC
 A1       
 A1      
 A1       
 A1
```

The desired result is

```
 Group   Skill
 A1      ABC
 A1      ABC
 A1      ABC
 A1      ABC
 A1      A1
 A1      A1
 A1      A1
 A1      A1
```

The result I'm getting now

```
Group   Skill
 A1      A1
 A1      A1
 A1      A1
 A1      A1
 A1      A1
 A1      A1
 A1      A1
 A1      A1
```

The if statement I wrote is

```
df<- read.csv("Data.csv",header=T,na.strings=c(""))
if (is.na(df$Skill)) {
    df$Skill <- df$Group
      }
```

Comment: `ifelse(is.na(df$Skill), df$Group, df$Skill)`

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use the `coalesce` function from the `dplyr` package:

```
require(dplyr)
df$Skill = coalesce(df$Skill, df$Group)
```

For rows where `Skill` has a non `NA` value, the value would remain as is.  Otherwise, the `NA` would be replaced with whatever is in the `Group` column.

Comment: Hi @Tim Biegeleisen
Thanks for your reply. But after I ran the 2 lines you've mentioned above, I got a Warning message in the console:
     "Warning message:
      In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  :
      invalid factor level, NA generated"
And the df$Skill column is still the same with some values & some 'NA' values

Answer (score 0):

This would be a solution with base R subsetting:

```
    df$Skill[is.na(df$Skill)] <- df$Group[is.na(df$Skill)]
```

Or with **dplyr**:

```
    library(dplyr)
    df %>% mutate(Skill = ifelse(is.na(Skill, Group, Skill))
```

It takes the Group value if Skill is NA and the Skill value if a Skill value exists.